# How should I solve this triple integral?

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates, multiple-integral

Hi everybody I have a triple integral I can't solve:

> $$\iiint \sqrt {x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dx \,dy \,dz $$

Which the region is between $z=\sqrt {x^2+y^2}$ and $z=4$ .
The question says after using the spherical coordinates the answer is:

> $${a\Large\int} _{0}^{\pi/4} \frac{(\sin \phi)d\phi}{\cos^4\phi} $$

So I've used the spherical coordinates $0<r<4$ and $ 0<\theta<2\pi$ and $0<\phi<\frac{\pi}{2}$. The things I don't get is first why is $\phi$ varying between 0 and $\frac{\pi}{4}$ instead of $\frac{\pi}{2}$? And secondly where did that $\cos^4\phi$ came from?

By the way the question asks for the value of $a$.

Comment: EDIT: ok now i understand the ϕ<π/4 it's because if we put x=0 in z=√ x^2+y^2we will get z=+y and z = -y which explains the ϕ bounds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plane $z=4$ has equation $r=4\sec \phi.$ So your limits for $r$ are $0\leq r \leq 4\sec \phi.$

Comment: wow i can't believe how much time i wasted for this only because i was trying with the cylinder "r" concept . thank you